# https worked on emulator but not on actual phone

Tags: .net, android, https, httpclient

I am developing Android app calling .net web service on https using server ssl certificate. It worked well on emulator but on actual phone, Vodafone 845, it's always giving me SocketTimeoutException after given 90ms (http works ok on both emulator and phone).

Anyone experieneced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3334) that may be your problem. SSL doesn't work properly if there's a proxy set for the APN.

The 'work around' is to clone the APN and remove the proxy settings. This has been reported on 2.1,2.2, and 2.3

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My phone is using Vodafone NZ with no proxy and I can browse known https site. So I guess my app has a problem. ?

Comment: It turned out that it was my stupid fault. Self-signed server certificate had been created as valid for several days (7 not sure) by default. I just replaced it with a new certificate with longer expiry and it worked. A bug Phil said seemed quite popular but not for vodafone 845 nz.